# docker app postgres local connection

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have created a docker image with playframework backend that connects to pgsql localhost database. It is running smoothly when I run it in my local machine but when I run it in docker I receive errors.

I want to connect the docker container to my posgresql localhost.

I have tried configuring postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf to open the port 5432

**pg_hba.conf**

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS             

    METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          trust
host    all             all             172.17.0.0/16           trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             172.17.0.0/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

**postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'      
                    # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432
```

When running my playframework app. I am getting the error below

```
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
```

On a side note, postgresql is installed using brew, running correctly can access database using pgadmin4.

Comment: I don't really know how you're connecting but I suspert from your playcontainer to localhost where you expect postgres to be running. BUT, localhost for your playcontainer = localhost inside the container and NOT localhost on your host (like you were expecting probably). Postgres is not running inside your playcontainer so it fails. To connect to postgres you need to use the containername of postgres (example: postgres:5432) OR mapping the postgresport (-p 5432:5432) on your host and connecting with IP:5432